# How do I update ROS?

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I *just* received my Kinect.  I am in the process of installing ubuntu 11.04.  I had a prior version of ROS installed... Is there a simple way to upgrade the current installation?

Sorry, this is a very newbie question.  I've spent a little time searching for the answer but it hasn't jumped out at me.

-Mike

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/10419/how-do-i-update-ros?/) by [mbahr](https://answers.ros.org/users/106/mbahr/) on ROS Answers with karma: 31 on 2011-06-27

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

If you got ROS from package manager, try

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
```

Huan

---

Originally posted by [liuhuanjim013](https://answers.ros.org/users/446/liuhuanjim013/) with karma: 152 on 2011-06-27

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 6

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Martin Günther](https://answers.ros.org/users/22/martin-g%C3%BCnther/) on 2011-07-20**:
Simple: use Synaptic or aptitude or whatever to remove the ros-cturtle-* packages and install the ros-diamondback-* packages you need.

**Comment by [sam](https://answers.ros.org/users/189/sam/) on 2011-07-20**:
My last opinion maybe incorrect. I have tried on cturtle with dist-upgrade,it doesn't upgrade to diamondback, but only upgrade all the cturtle packages. So how to upgrade cturtle to diamondback?Thank you~

**Comment by [sam](https://answers.ros.org/users/189/sam/) on 2011-07-20**:
I figured out that dist-upgrade is not only for ROS. Why dist-upgrade can upgrade the ROS version not just upgrade all the packages of ROS?

**Comment by [Martin Günther](https://answers.ros.org/users/22/martin-g%C3%BCnther/) on 2011-07-20**:
No, 'dist-upgrade' will not upgrade ubuntu. You can also just do a normal 'apt-get upgrade' instead. (The difference between 'upgrade' and 'dist-upgrade' is that 'dist-upgrade' does some stuff to handle changed dependencies etc. correctly.)

**Comment by [sam](https://answers.ros.org/users/189/sam/) on 2011-07-20**:
Is 'apt-get dist-upgrade' only for upgrade ROS version or it will also upgrade ubuntu?  And how to only update ROS packages?

**Comment by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) on 2011-06-28**:
Also make sure they read packages.ros.org not code.ros.org.  The code.ros.org debian repo is deprecated.  http://www.ros.org/wiki/diamondback/Installation/Ubuntu#diamondback.2BAC8-Installation.2BAC8-Sources.Setup_your_sources.list

**Comment by [Martin Günther](https://answers.ros.org/users/22/martin-g%C3%BCnther/) on 2011-06-28**:
Exactly. Before doing that however, you should have a look at the file /etc/apt/sources.list.d/ros-latest.list and uncomment the lines starting with "deb" (remove the #). They are commented out automatically during upgrade. (I am assuming you are upgrading from Ubuntu 10.10 to 11.04?)